# Flask app en Plesk con wsgi no funciona

Tags: python, flask, plesk

Por favor ten en cuenta que estoy operando en Plesk, que este es mi primer sitio web y estoy siguiendo un tutorial que encontré en youtube: Para empezar te diré las librerías que instale.

Apache ya estaba instalado, libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 -y, instale también flask y flask_sqlalchemy

Ahora te diré la ruta de mis archivos: `/var/www/vhosts/cap-0.com/httpdocs/httpdocs` en el segundo httpdocs se encuentra mi aplicación flask, en el primer directorio puse una programación recomendada en el video con el siguiente comando:

```bash
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/httpdocs.conf
```

y la configuración puesta en el directorio fue:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 62.151.183.134
        ServerAdmin email@mywebsite.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/cap-0.com/httpdocs/httpdocs.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/cap-0.com/httpdocs/httpdocs/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/vhosts/cap-0.com/httpdocs/httpdocs/static
        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/cap-0.com/httpdocs/httpdocs/static/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

luego use los comandos:

```bash
sudo a2ensite httpdocs
systemctl reload apache2
```

luego cree en el primer httpdocs un archivo wsgi con el siguiente comando:

```bash
sudo nano httpdos.wsgi
```

y a ese archivo le puse el siguiente código:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/vhosts/cap-0.com/httpdocs/")

from httpdocs import app as application
application.secret_key = 'Add your secret key'
```

después de eso reinicie apache:

```bash
sudo service apache2 restart
```

y según la guía que estaba siguiendo ya debería funcionar pero al entrar al sitio web me da el error **403 forbidden** y no me deja cambiar los permisos del archivo wsgi por medio del panel de plesk.

Eso es todo lo que he hecho, de nuevo te recuerdo que soy un noob en esto y no se si en plesk es totalmente diferente el proceso y si ese es el caso estoy dispuesto a cambiar todo el proceso, agradecería mucho la ayuda y gracias por tomarte el tiempo de leer todo esto.

Comment: Verifica los logs de apache, especialmente el error.log. Es probable que lo que está ocurriendo es que apache no tenga permisos de lectura de alguno de los archivos necesarios, por ejemplo al .wsgi que explicas que creaste usando `sudo` (lo que me hace pensar que quedó como propietario el `root`. Si ese es el caso, puedes cambiarle de propietario o puedes cambiar los permisos para que el usuario con el que corre apache tenga acceso de lectura al archivo y a la cadena de carpetas donde está contenido ese archivo.